# AngularJS app isn't passing data correctly to Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, angularjs, express

I'm not even exactly sure what the problem is here, I've been trying to figure it out for a couple days. I'm somewhat new to the MEAN stack, so I'm probably missing something obvious. I basically copied the boilerplate code for the [mean.io](https://github.com/linnovate/mean) back-end controllers, models, and routes and Angular controllers, views, and services. I'm now getting this error when I create a new Client via the browser:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" at path "_id"
    at ObjectId.cast (/Users/d/Web/personal/mean-app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectid.js:116:13)
    at ObjectId.castForQuery (/Users/d/Web/personal/mean-app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectid.js:165:17)
    at Query.cast (/Users/d/Web/personal/mean-app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2270:32)
    at Query.findOne (/Users/d/Web/personal/mean-app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1117:10)
    at Query.exec (/Users/d/Web/personal/mean-app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mquery/lib/mquery.js:2181:16)
    at Query.exec (/Users/d/Web/personal/mean-app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1748:19)
    at Function.ClientSchema.statics.load (/Users/d/Web/personal/mean-app/app/models/client.js:80:48)
    at exports.client (/Users/d/Web/personal/mean-app/app/controllers/clients.js:15:12)
    at paramCallback (/Users/d/Web/personal/mean-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:151:7)
    at param (/Users/d/Web/personal/mean-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:133:11)
```

**controllers/clients.js:**

```
exports.client = function(req, res, next, id) {
    Client.load(id, function(err, client) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (!client) return next(new Error('Failed to load client ' + id));
        req.client = client;
        next();
    });
};
```

**models/client.js:**

```
ClientSchema.statics.load = function(id, cb) {
    this.findOne({ _id: id }).populate('user').exec(cb);
};
```

When I insert a client via the mongo shell manually (`db.clients.save({ name: "Bob" })`), it saves and appears in Node, but when I go to edit it via the Angular view, it can't save, giving me a similar error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

I'm thinking that perhaps this means that my back-end code is find and it's the front-end code that isn't communicating all the necessary data to the back-end. For reference:

**public/js/controllers/clients.js**

```
angular.module('mean.clients').controller('ClientsController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', 'Global', 'Clients', function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, Global, Clients) {
    $scope.global = Global;

    $scope.create = function() {
        var client = new Clients({
            name: this.name,
            contactName: this.contactName
        });
        client.$save(function(response) {
            $location.path('clients/' + response._id);
        });

        this.name = '';
        this.contactName = '';
    };

    // etc.
}]);
```

**public/js/services/clients.js**

```
angular.module('mean.clients').factory('Clients', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('clients/:clientId', {
        clientId: '@_id'
    }, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Wait, I'm a complete idiot, I didn't modify the boilerplate code of $scope.create(). Ha!

Comment: Turns out that wasn't the problem. Still having the same issue as before.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to include the _id in your client object.

Comment: Where? In the mongoose Schema? I thought it was automatically added.

Comment: public/js/controllers/clients.js          var client = new Clients({_id: this.id,
            name: this.name,
            contactName: this.contactName
        });

Comment: Nope _id is auto generated, unless you set a specific value.

Comment: I'm  not sure what happened or what I changed but it's working now...? Maybe it was a cache issue with one of the Angular files.